# jQuery: Making every header of paragraph position fixed using viewport

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, viewport

I have a set of articles with paragraphs. I am trying to make every header/title of each article to have a fixed position when ever the user scrolls onto that article, without using the viewport plugin.

This is what I am using:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var $divs = $('div');

    var top = $.grep($divs, function(item) {
        return $(item).position().top <= winTop;
    });

    $divs.removeClass('active');
    $(top).addClass('active');

});
```

On my example, every title gets position fixed while passing through it, and im ending up having all titles with position fixed.

### **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C2SWa/**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I just found from long time ago when I learn jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header1" class="header fixed">
    <h2>Header1</h2>
</div>
<div id="header1_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<div id="header2" class="header relative">
    <h2>Header2</h2>
</div>
<div id="header2_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>

<div id="header3" class="header relative">
    <h2>Header3</h2>
</div>
<div id="header3_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

.header {
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.header h2 {
    margin:20px;
}

.fixed {
    position:fixed;
}

.relative {
    position:static;
}

#header1_content {
    margin-top:80px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
       var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (currentScrollTop > lastScrollTop){

            // Scrolling down
            $('.header').each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('fixed'))
                { 
                    var _next_header = $(this).nextUntil('.header').next('.header');
                    if($(_next_header).length > 0)
                    {
                        if(($(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) >= $(_next_header).offset().top)
                        {
                            // Bottom of header hit top of next header
                            $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('relative');
                            $(_next_header).removeClass('relative').addClass('fixed');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Scrolling up
            $('.header').each(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('fixed'))
                { 
                    var _prev_header = $(this).prevUntil('.header').prev('.header');
                    if($(_prev_header ).length > 0)
                    {
                        if($(this).offset().top <= ($('#' + $(_prev_header).attr('id') + '_content').offset().top + $(this).height()))
                        {
                            // Top of header hit bottom of previous content box
                            $(this).removeClass('fixed').addClass('relative');
                            $(_prev_header).removeClass('relative').addClass('fixed');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
        lastScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj4nN/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use this jQuery plugin:  [jQuery.stickysectionheaders](http://polarblau.github.io/stickySectionHeaders/)